# Postfix virtual aliases & domains?

Tags: linux, postfix

I am using Postfix & Dovecot on a VPS (Ubuntu 15.04 64 bits) at [OVH](http://ovh.com/) in France for a *small* user base (a big dozen of users, mostly my family, less than a thousand email/day, including spam) for two DNS domains, let's call them `starynk.net` & `melt.org` (the actual ones are slightly different, but you could guess them easily). Most of the emails are to `starynk.net`, and a very few email addresses on `melt.org` might be *aliases* to `@starynk.net`

`postfix` package is version 2.11.3-1ubuntu1, `dovecot-core`   package is 1:2.2.9-1ubuntu5

I followed carefully the instructions on http://www.binarytides.com/install-postfix-dovecot-debian/ and it works (at last!) because I can send & receive mails on my home Debian Linux PC (which is *not* the VPS server at OVH) to my address `basile@starynk.net`

I guess that the significant configuration is in my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` :

```
# grep virtual /etc/postfix/main.cf 
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
```

with the file `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains` containing:

```
# file /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains by Basile
starynk.net OK
melt.org OK
```

I want to add some alias emails for `starynk.net` (e.g: `john@starynk.net` -> `john.starynk99@gmail.com` ....) and for `melt.org` (e.g. `webmaster@melt.org` -> `basile@starynk.net`)

Of course, editing `/etc/aliases`  then running `newaliases` does not work.

I guess that I need [virtual alias domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) so I probably need to add *somewhere* in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` (but is the order important there?) a line like

```
 virtual_alias_domains = starynk.net melt.org
 virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtualaliases
```

(is that correct? is that compatible with the existing settings?)

and finally put in that new `/etc/postfix/virtualaliases` file lines like

```
## file /etc/postfix/virtualaliases by Basile
matt@starynk.net: matt.star11@gmail.com
john@starynk.net: john.starynk99@gmail.com
family@starynk.net: matt@starynk.net, john@starynk.net 
webmaster@melt.org: basile@starynk.net
```

When I run as root `postmap /etc/postfix/virtualaliases`  it looks I am getting warnings for every entry:

```
postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/virtualaliases, line 2: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/virtualaliases, line 3: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/virtualaliases, line 4: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/virtualaliases, line 5: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
```

---

but then, what is the `newaliases`  command to run after editing the file above? Can it accept pipe notation as documented in Postfix' [aliases(5)](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) ?

At last, how to test the configuration of a Postfix system? is there a Postfix command (which I would use to test my new Postfix configuration) explaining what happens to an email to `webmaster@melt.org` *without* having to send an actual email ?

### not working yet!

I am doing `service postfix restart` after the `postmap` command but it does not work:

```
<family@starynk.net>: host
mail.starynk.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1
<family@starynk.net> User doesn't exist:
family@starynk.net (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

with

```
 Reporting-MTA: dns; mail.starynk.net
 X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 4BDE761BFE
 X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; basile@starynk.net
 Arrival-Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 10:08:07 +0100 (CET)

 Final-Recipient: rfc822; family@starynk.net
 Original-Recipient: rfc822;family@starynk.net
 Action: failed
 Status: 5.1.1
 Remote-MTA: dns; mail.starynk.net
 Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 <family@starynk.net> User doesn't
   exist: family@starynk.net
```

---

### working (sortof)

I finally managed to have something working. My `/etc/postfix/virtualaliases` file has lines like:

```
# file /etc/postfix/virtualaliases by Basile without colons or commas
matt@starynk.net matt.star11@gmail.com
john@starynk.net john.starynk99@gmail.com
family@starynk.net matt@starynk.net john@starynk.net 
webmaster@melt.org basile@starynk.net
```

(of course I have to run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtualaliases` after every change)

but I still don't understand how could I have some alias to a Unix command pipe, and I am surprised by the lack of commas (which [virtual(5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) is suggesting)

Comment: Have you tried without `virtual_alias_domains`? In my setup i have only `virtual_alias_maps` configured and i have several domains. See [docs](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#virtual_alias_class) for an explanation of those two.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/my/file` as written in the postfix man page, you have to create the database with `postmap /my/file` everytime you change `/my/file`.

I don't know any function ir feature of postfix, which provides a "dry-run" action. You should test it in a VM locally, using a local dns and mailserver.

It won't affect any other configuration option.

Comment: But `virtual_alias_maps` won't interfere with other settings, including `virtual_mailbox_domains` ?

Comment: No. Every configuraton option accepts its own database. It also possible to connect it to an ldap server or a mysql database. The default type is a postmap.

Comment: Setting one option does not affect another one as long as there are no config errors. (Trying to redirect a alias whoes domain is not listed.)

Comment: @EllDevender: it would be nice if you could edit your answer....

Comment: @EllDevender: I did the modification, and it does not work. How should I debug the issue?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Does postfix start successfully? Please try it with a test mail and post any output of "mail.log" or "syslog".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33688/discussion-between-elidevender-and-basile-starynkevitch).